# Can I pan (animate the x value) an image that is being clip-pathed by an svg without moving the clipping SVG's x value?

Tags: css, animation, svg, clip-path

I am trying to pan the visible area of an image within a clip path. I do not want the area of image to move, only what part of the image is visible through the clipping (This way the clipping area would pan across the image like if you were to walk across a room while looking through a window, the window stays still, but what you can see in the window changes).

I tried using `transform: translateX()` on the image, but that moved the whole shape.

I expected that to work because adjusting the inline `x` and `y` value on the image element itself is having the desired result, the image itself is moving, not the location of the SVG.

---

I found the following js fiddle which gets something similar to what I am looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/zut81dng/4/.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your SVG to the bare necesities; you have a lot of variables to play with:

```html
<svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="0 0 200 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="pink"></rect>
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <path d="m118 140-4 2-5-3-1-4-3-8-5-4-5-1-3-10-6-13-9-4-4-4-3-5-4-4-5-3-5-6-6-5-9
-4-1-3-5-6-1-3-7-11-7 0-8-5-3-3-1-4 2-4 5-2-1-4 13-5 19-9 15-2 34-1 5 4 3 7 9-1 
26-3 6 2 26 16 21 17-11 11-5 13-1 13-3 2-2 6-5 1-4 8-6 6-5 7-3 2-8 7-6 0 2 7-10 11z"/>
  </clipPath>
  <image y="-50" x="-50" clip-path="url(#clip)" height="200%" width="200%" 
         href="https://www.bahai.org/chrome/img/home/home-feature-4.jpg?4ed4f07d">
    <animate attributeName="x" 
             values="-50;0;50;0;-50" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the image around an [animate element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) allows for the desired effect:

```html
<svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <clipPath id="svg-clip">
            <path id="SVG-for-clipping" d="m418.17 153.221-3.758 2.088-5.428-2.714-1.253-4.384-2.714-7.516-4.802-4.385-5.428-1.252-3.34-10.022-5.637-12.526-8.769-3.967-4.384-3.967-2.715-5.428-4.384-4.1755-4.802-2.7141-4.802-6.0546-6.472-4.8019-9.395-3.7579-1.044-3.1317-5.01-6.0545-1.044-3.1317-7.098-10.8564-7.099.4175-8.351-5.0106-2.714-2.7141-.626-3.758 1.67-3.9668 4.802-2.0877-.627-4.3843 12.736-5.4283 18.998-9.3949 15.241-1.6702 34.448-1.0439 4.802 3.9667 3.341 6.6809 9.186-1.0439 26.306-3.1316 6.054 1.6702 26.306 15.867 21.087 16.911-11.274 11.4827-5.428 12.7354-1.044 13.153-3.341 1.6702-2.296 5.637-5.011 1.253-4.384 7.516-5.637 5.637-4.802 7.098-3.341 1.67-7.516 7.099-6.054.417 2.088 6.681-10.439 11.483z" />
        </clipPath>
        <image
        y="-100"
        x="0"
        id="fill-image" clip-path="url(#svg-clip)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://www.bahai.org/chrome/img/home/home-feature-4.jpg?4ed4f07d">
            <animate attributeName="x" values="-0;50;0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </image>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you hit that [ < > ] button in the editor you can make it a running SO Snippet, and we can click one button to see the effect  (I didn't want to edit your answer to see what is going on)

Comment: Hmm, it was working in the snippet edit menu, but the run code snippet button seems unresponsive now that I've added it.

Comment: Hmm.. you found a bug??? The font of the button is different...

Answer (score 0):

Clip paths that are specified on an element are transformed with the element.

The solution is to wrap your element in a group `<g>` element, and apply the clip path to that instead.  Then you can move the child element without affecting the clip path.

```
<g clip-path="">
   <image ... or whatever.../>
</g>
```